# Can't manage to clean up simple webscraped description

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to extract a description but I cant get rid of everything around it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
my_url = "https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-882792877-donativo-para-gt710-me-ayudas-_JM#position=1&type=item&tracking_id=65132519-fce6-4449-afe0-c36e112f4638"
uclient = urlopen(my_url)
htmlreader = uclient.read()
page_soup= soup(htmlreader,"html.parser")
containers = page_soup.find("p",{"class":"ui-pdp-description__content"})
print(containers)
```

I get this as a result

```
<p class="ui-pdp-description__content">.Me ayudas a conseguir una plaquita de video para que mi nene juegue roblox? Muchas gracias de antemano.<br/></p>
```

I need it like this

```
Me ayudas a conseguir una plaquita de video para que mi nene juegue roblox? Muchas gracias de antemano
```

I tried containers.string but get  "none" as a result.

Comment: in last line use this code print(containers.text[1:])

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Please vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is absolutely right. At the end just do

`print(containers.text)`

This removes all the HTML tags and what's left is the string you want.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you would verify my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure on what The best way to do this is but if you run the following code

```
 print(containers.prettify().split('>')[1].replace('<br/', ''))
```

it will return a string that only includes the sentence that you are trying to print.